# Simple Issue in User Login

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I am already done with this, But stuck up with a minor mistake and can't find where it is.

Here is my Controller :

```
 public function CreateUserProcess()
    {
        $user = new User;
        $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
        $user->UserName = Input::get('UserName');
        if($user->save())
        {
            return Redirect::to('createuser')->with('Message', 'User Details Saved Succesfully');
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::to('createuser')->with('Message', 'Error');
        }
    }
```

This is to create a User with UserName and Password with default laravel's BCrypt Hashing

Here is my Login Controller :

```
public function Login()
{
    $UserName = Input::get('UserName');
    $password = Input::get('password');       
    if (Auth::attempt(array('UserName' => $UserName, 'password' => $password)))
    {
        return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
    }
    else
    {
    $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
    print_r(end($queries));
    }
}
```

And My Table has only 4 fields: id, UserName, password and remember_token

I can able to create user, But i can't able to check the Login Process.

I am able to see the UserName and Password once it is sent to the controller but i am stuckup with this step

```
    if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $UserName, 'password' => $password)))
```

What is the mistake i am doing and how can i fix this ?

Whenever i try to login,

i am getting this

```
Array ( [query] => select * from `users` where `UserName` = ? limit 1 [bindings] => Array ( [0] => admin ) [time] => 0 )
```

Comment: Is your password in the db hashed and the field at **least 60 characters long**?

Comment: can you show the fields you have in the 'users' table? I think the bug is that you give the attempt function 'UserName' insted of 'email'

Answer (score 0):

Why is there email in your attempt.

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $UserName, 'password' => $password)))
```

change it to

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('Username' => $UserName, 'password' => $password)))
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, I have updated the question. But it was still the same

Comment: This code is working on mine. Remove else condition from your controller and on your config/app.php turn 'debug' => true. It will show you the bug. Try to solve that.

Comment: The debug was already true, If i remove the else condition, only the blank screen appears,,

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('UserName' => $UserName, 'password' => $password)))
```

Check if you have 'UserName' column in your database table, maybe it's 'username'